# The hardest one I believe

Tags: no-computers, sudoku

If you are really smart solve this Sudoku within a day

[image]

BEST OF LUCK

Comment: You probably want to add a no-computers tag, otherwise it's perfectly straightforward :-)

Comment: As @mocarsha2019 has noted, this is "the world's hardest sudoku" and has already been featured on Puzzling SE, and the solution has already been found: 862 751 349 / 943 628 157 / 571 493 286 / 159 387 624 / 386 245 791 / 724 169 835 / 217 934 568 / 438 576 912 / 695 812 473

Comment: @Kroob.D warning . 3/4 of your questions are duplicate. If you keep on doing same thing ,no more questions will be accepted from this site(puzzling stack exchange) so take care :/